# What other times have there been a Queen's Speech without a majority government?

Tags: united-kingdom, constitutional-monarchy

So the Queen's Speech is today and [The Conservatives have a minority government](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/queens-speech-delay-21-june-therea-may-dup-deal-minority-government-conservatives-tory-northern-a7791086.html), which got me wondering, what other times has a Queen's Speech occurred without a majority government?

Comment: Here is a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_government#United_Kingdom) of minority and coalition governments in the UK since 1945. The Queen's Speech took place (usually) once a year when such a government was in office.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since 1852, there have been 8 elections which resulted in no party getting a majority or forming any coalition - 1885, 1892, 1910, 1923, 1929, 1974 and 2017. (from Wikipedia - [List of United Kingdom general elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_Kingdom_general_elections))

<sup>* This doesn't include elections in which a coalition government's formed, e.g. 2010, since a coalition government is theoretically a majority government.</sup>

---

It's worth noting that the Queen's speech (or the King's speech, officially known as the **speech from the throne started in 1852**.

> **History of State Opening**
>
> Traditions surrounding State Opening and the delivery of a speech by the monarch can be traced back as far as the 16th century. The current ceremony dates from the opening of the rebuilt Palace of Westminster in 1852 after the fire of 1834.
>
> <sup>Source: http://www.parliament.uk/about/how/occasions/stateopening/</sup>

---

- 1885 (speech defeated) – An amendment was passed on the Queen's speech.

  - Queen Victoria [delivered her speech in January 1886](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/lords/1886/jan/21/the-queens-speech).
  - > The Liberals and the IPP passed an amendment to the Queen’s speech and Salisbury’s government fell.
    > <sup>Source: http://theconversation.com/hung-parliaments-have-voted-down-the-queens-speech-before-heres-what-happened-79384</sup>
- 1892 (speech defeated) - The new government lost the vote on the Queen’s speech.

  - Queen Victoria [delivered her speech in August](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/lords/1892/aug/08/the-queens-speech).
  - > The Irish had the balance of power and once again Gladstone’s support for Irish home rule ensured they supported a Liberal “no confidence” amendment to the new government’s Queen’s speech which Salisbury had put forward. Gladstone then formed a government and passed a second Home Rule Bill in the Commons – though it was defeated in the Lords.
    > <sup>Source: http://theconversation.com/hung-parliaments-have-voted-down-the-queens-speech-before-heres-what-happened-79384</sup>
- 1910 – In 1910, there was a Liberal minority government following the [Jan 1910 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_general_election,_January_1910).

  - King Edward VII [delivered his speech in February](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/lords/1910/feb/21/the-kings-speech).
- 1923 (speech defeated) – There was a hung parliament following the [1923 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_general_election,_1923). Conservative leader Stanley Baldwin had his King's speech defeated which forced him to resign.

  - King George V [delivered his speech in February](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/lords/1923/feb/13/the-kings-speech).
  - > Conservative leader Stanley Baldwin had fought the campaign on tariff reform, anathema to liberal free trade principles, and the Liberals and Labour combined to defeat the Conservative King’s speech in early 1924.
    > <sup>Source: http://theconversation.com/hung-parliaments-have-voted-down-the-queens-speech-before-heres-what-happened-79384</sup>
- 1929 – A minority government was formed again in 1929 after [the election that year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_general_election,_1929).

  - King George V delivered [his speech in July](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/lords/1929/jul/02/the-kings-speech).
- 1974 – It occurred [in 1974](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/commons/1974/mar/12/queens-speech) when a minority Labour government was formed following [the Feb 1974 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_general_election,_February_1974).

  - Queen Elizabeth II [delivered her speech in March](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/commons/1974/mar/12/queens-speech).

Comment: So it's not exactly a precedent (for the monarchy) but is for Queen Elizabeth II. I thought as much, seems it looks like Theresa May is breaking a few traditions this election cycle. Thanks for yet another informative and extensive answer.

Comment: @BradleyWilson Yup, Queen Elizabeth II's speech in 1974 was also during a minority government. You're welcome! :)